# Search Files of Notepad++ and remove char

Tags: notepad++

I am attempting to use Notepad++ to remove underscores from the end of text names in both the file name and file itself of a GUI.

The underscores were erroneously added to fulfill an 8-char minimum for the button names originally, but this is no longer required.

I'd like to design a script and use the text file names as a data set, search each text file, find the specific button names with underscores and remove those underscores as this task would be better suited for automation (over 10,000 buttons to search through).

I have a rough idea of how to do it but have never really done anything in C++ and this would be my first project.

**What I've done so far:**

I have tried to compile the text names into a separate folder, using notepad++ to produce an equation to scrape the information from the second file list, but I'm unfamiliar with the process to call another file and how to execute the code, in general.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to accomplish executing a text file and what additional steps I'd need to take to search the file list.

Also: Can Notepad++ even be automated without the use of other tools to remove symbols from thousands of different text files in a singular folder?

**Edit:**

I have a folder and it contains thousands of files with names like:
Unit1__.txt
Unit2__.txt
....
Unit_X__.txt

Inside each of these files, there is code for a GUI. The GUI code that I would need to change is for a button.

Inside each file, I would like to change the name of the GUI button.
Ex: "Unit1__" ---> "Unit1" inside of the "Unit1__.txt file"

The file names I would also like to change.
Ex. "Unit1__.txt" ---> "Unit1.txt" to reflect the button change in the GUI

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Perhaps including some examples will help.

Comment: This is not a job for Notepad++, you'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language, Python, Perl, PowerShell...

Answer (score 0):

I post following solution as a pragmatic one for Windows. You be warned - please make a **backup copy** of all files first.

I assume your files e.g `Unit01__.txt` all have the extension *.txt and reside in folder e.g. **D:\_temp**.

- First open **one** of the files in your working directory by Notepad++
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> - goes to the *Find in Files* tab
- Find what: `Unit\_\_` - *or another RegEx for your needs*
- Replace with:``Unit`
- Filters: `*__.txt`
- Directory: e.g. D:\_temp
- Check `Match case`
- Search mode: `Regular expression`
- Test this by <kbd>Find All</kbd> and check the result
- Click on <kbd>Replace in Files</kbd>
- Click on <kbd>OK</kbd> when you're really sure.

Please note, Notepad++ is a text editor, not a filesystem-maintenance/renaming utility.

This said, as a second step you should have been moved to the folder containing your files and open a cmd console window. Type in

```
dir /b /od *__.txt > Rename.bat
```

This is resulting in a list of all names of the files, of current folder, are re-written, sorted by increasing date of modification, in a file named Rename.bat

- Open this `Rename.bat` in Notepad++
- Open the Replace dialog <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- **Find what:** `(^.*)(\_\_)(\.txt)`
- **Replace with:** `ren\x20"$0"\x20"$1$3"`

You'd get something like this:

```
ren "Unit__.txt" "Unit.txt"
ren "Unit01__.txt" "Unit01.txt"
ren "Unit02__.txt" "Unit02.txt"
```

Add the line `@echo OFF`, at the very beginning of this batch file, to prevent the echo of commands on the console window.

```
@echo OFF
ren "Unit__.txt" "Unit.txt"
ren "Unit01__.txt" "Unit01.txt"
ren "Unit02__.txt" "Unit02.txt"
```

Save the file and exit Notepad++. You may edit Rename.bat for your needs.

Type in `Rename.bat` on the console window and hit the Enter key to start the renaming process.